# Update app ALM Api in sharepoint site not giving proper response

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx, alm, pnp-js

I have tried updating the apps in sharepoint site using pnp/sp in spfx webpart

```
import { Web } from "@pnp/sp/webs";

  public static async UpdateApp(id, web) {
    var app = web.getAppCatalog().getAppById(id);
   var response= await app.upgrade();
  }
```

even I am awaiting for app to be upgraded .pnp is not sending any proper response. please help how I can find how to find upgrade is completed or not